# How does the Jenkins master communicate with my custom container in Kubernetes?

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes

I am using the [Jenkins Kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) to spin up **ephemeral** agents on AWS EKS. My master is located on premise and the connection to AWS is done over AWS Direct Connect.

I understood that the plugin always spins up a jnlp container in conjunction with my custom container which should run my workload.

Can some one explain to me how the communication chain from evoking e.g. a git command from the pipeline started from my master, actually reaches the custom container and executes the git command? To be more specific: What happens after the jnlp from master to slave? How does stuff communicate with my custom container?

Below is my pipeline Jenkinsfile which runs on the master. I try to checkout a repository on my ephemeral container and afterwards run a function defined from my jenkins-shared-library (myJenkinsLib.buildWithBuildah(...)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Library('jenkins-shared-library')



def args = [

... some args

];


pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {

      label 'kubernetes-cloud-agent'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: buildah
    image: <my-custom-buildah-image-on-ecr>
  - name: jnlp
    image: <custom-jnlp-pushed-on-ecr-out-of-connectivity-reasons>
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Run build') {
      steps {
        container('buildah') {

          dir('/home/jenkins/agent') {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "main"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "<git-url-to-private-repo-using-ssh>"]]])
          
            dir('<repo-name>') {
              script {
                myJenkinsLib.buildWithBuildah(args);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```